# Can i create a webhook to get check in info?

Tags: eventbrite

Is it possible to have a webhook invoked when an attendee checks-in an event?

If not is there a way to get this information in "real-time"?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, but this is something that we hope to implement in our next Sprint. I'll let you know as well as announce on our social media channels when this is available.